# The method of all possible regressions in R

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics

I want to determine which variables are best suited for the model. To do this, I use the method of all possible regressions, i.e. build models with all possible combinations of predictors. For example:

```
library(fpp2)

# uschange is dataset from "fpp2" package
train <- ts(uschange[1:180, ], start = 1970, frequency = 5)

fit1 <- tslm(Consumption ~ Income, data = train)
fit2 <- tslm(Consumption ~ Production, data = train)
fit3 <- tslm(Consumption ~ Savings, data = train)
fit4 <- tslm(Consumption ~ Unemployment, data = train)
fit5 <- tslm(Consumption ~ Income + Production, data = train)
fit6 <- tslm(Consumption ~ Income + Savings, data = train)
# and so on...
```

After that, I need to evaluate the models in two ways:

```
test <- data.frame(
  Income = uschange[181:187, 2],
  Production = uschange[181:187, 3],
  Savings = uschange[181:187, 4],
  Unemployment = uschange[181:187, 5]
)

y <- uschange[181:187, 1]

CV(fit1)
accuracy(forecast(fit1, test), y)

CV(fit2)
accuracy(forecast(fit2, test), y)

CV(fit3)
accuracy(forecast(fit3, test), y)
# and so on...
```

As a result, I want to get a model with the smallest value of `AICc` from `CV()` and with the smallest error value (for example `MAE` from `accuracy()`).
How can I do this automatically?

EDIT:

```
> dput(head(uschange, 20))
structure(c(0.615986218, 0.46037569, 0.876791423, -0.274245141, 
1.897370758, 0.911992909, 0.794538845, 1.648587467, 1.313722178, 
1.891474954, 1.530714, 2.318294715, 1.81073916, -0.041739961, 
0.354235565, -0.291632155, -0.877027936, 0.351135548, 0.409597702, 
-1.475808634, 0.972261043, 1.169084717, 1.55327055, -0.255272381, 
1.987153628, 1.447334175, 0.531811929, 1.160125137, 0.457011505, 
1.016624409, 1.904101264, 3.890258661, 0.708252663, 0.79430954, 
0.433818275, 1.093809792, -1.661684821, -0.938353209, 0.094487794, 
-0.122595985, -2.452700312, -0.551525087, -0.358707862, -2.185454855, 
1.90973412, 0.901535843, 0.308019416, 2.291304415, 4.149573867, 
1.89062398, 1.273352897, 3.436892066, 2.799076357, 0.817688618, 
0.868996932, 1.472961869, -0.882483578, 0.074279194, -0.41314971, 
-4.064118932, 4.810311502, 7.287992337, 7.289013063, 0.985229644, 
3.657770614, 6.051341804, -0.445832214, -1.53087186, -4.35859438, 
-5.054525795, 5.809959038, 16.04471706, -5.348868495, 8.426034362, 
2.758795652, 11.14642986, -2.533514487, -6.592644641, 0.51717884, 
11.3433954, 0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 0.7, -0.1, -0.1, 0.1, 0, -0.2, -0.1, 
-0.2, -0.3, -0.3, 0, -0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1.3), .Dim = c(20L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Consumption", "Income", "Production", 
"Savings", "Unemployment")), .Tsp = c(1970, 1974.75, 4), class = c("mts", 
"ts", "matrix"))
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(head(uschange, 20))`.

Comment: See here for a way of doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270580/logistic-regression-how-to-try-every-combination-of-predictors-in-r/45270966#45270966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# get all names of predictors
cols <- colnames(uschange)[-1]

# create all combinations
out <- unlist(lapply(1:length(cols), function(n) combn(cols, n, FUN=function(row) paste0("Consumption ~ ", paste0(row, collapse = "+")))))


# fit models:
mods = lapply(out, function(frml) tslm(frml, data=train))

# define helper function:
cv_this <- function(x){
  return(list('cv' = CV(x), 'acc' = accuracy(forecast(x, test), y)))
}

# run helper function over all models to get evaluations out:
lapply(mods, cv_this)
```